# Installing iptraf or iftop on ubuntu core

Tags: package-management, dpkg, snap

Hi I recently setup ubuntu core on a raspberry pi, I want to install both iftop and iptraf yet as ubuntu core only uses the snap package manager I can't seem to find a way to install it. I have downloaded the source for iftop and tried to compile it but the make command appears to be missing, I then tried installing iptraf via .deb package and dpkg returns an error about being unable to access the status area. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, Ubuntu Core only supports snaps. Regarding using iftop or iptraf (neither of which appear to be available as a snap), you have two options:

1. Snap them yourself. You can learn more about the snap format and packaging method at https://snapcraft.io.
2. Assuming these aren't needed in a production capacity and only for troubleshooting/development, you can install the [classic snap](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/developer-setup) and gain the ability to use `apt` (and debs) again, albeit in a somewhat limited capacity (it's essentially a chroot).